# How can I set only the players X rotation to 0 in Quaternion.Slerp in Unity?

Tags: unity, c#, rotation, quaternion, angles

I want to set the players X axis to zero while he is turning to the target Object but I dont get it to work.

Code:

---

public float rotationSpeed;

```
void OnMouseDown()
{
        //PLAYER ROTATION TO ORE OBJECT
        var rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(transform.position - player.transform.position);
        player.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp (player.transform.rotation, rotation, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
```

Comment: When you say you want to set their x axis to zero, do you mean you want to eliminate pitch, so that the player rotates only in the horizontal plane? Also, do you intend this motion to continue on frames after the player's initial mouse press?

Comment: I have shortened the code. When the player touches or is near an ore he should start digging and rotate the player to the ore but only on the Y axis because on this code my player starts rotation up on the X axis that he kinda looks above the ore that looks weird so I want to set the X axis to 0 that he only turns to the ore on the Y axis I hope I could explain my problem more detailed and no the motion should just stop there and not continue to set X axis to 0.

Comment: Cant I anyhow set the x Axis to zero by doing like player.transform.rotation.x = 0; I know this code doesnt work and gives errors but could it be like that way ?

Comment: Not really. Rotations aren't as neatly separable by axis as translations - it might look like they are locally, but when compounding effects stack up it matters in which order the axes are processed. There are times where x & y rotations combine to a z rotation for instance - the meaning of each component changes based on the state that came before. So it's generally safer to think of rotations in terms of what you want them to do to the character's facing vectors. Does the player ever need to tilt up/downhill, or can we assume your constraint is "keep the local y axis exactly vertical"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Quaternion.LookRotation` looks along the vector you pass it. So if you want that rotation to twist only in the horizontal plane, lock the input vector into that plane:

```
var offset = transform.position - player.transform.position;

// Remove any uphill / downhill component,
// so the rotation we get is a pure yaw rotation.
offset.y = 0;

var rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(offset);
```